# store the output of powershell command in a variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file

The following commnad:

```
$sun=PowerShell [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-8).ToString('dd-MMM-yyyy')

echo %sun %
```

the output of the echo is

> PowerShell [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-8).ToString('dd-MMM-yyyy')

how do i get it to output something like

> 22-Sep-2013

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `for /f`:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%x in (`powershell "(Get-Date).AddDays(-8).ToString('dd-MMM-yyyy')"`) do set sun=%%x
```